# “no matching architecture in universal wrapper” when importing pygame

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pygame

I have a very similar problem to the one this person had: ["no matching architecture in universal wrapper" when importing pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775948/no-matching-architecture-in-universal-wrapper-when-importing-pygame)

Anyway, I downloaded and installed Pygame, I run the program, and it gave me this error:

> File "anima.py", line 2, in 
>       import pygame 
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/**init**.py", line 95, in 
>       from pygame.base import *
>   ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper

Now, I tried to do some of the things they said in the previous question, but they are not working.
I am using a OS X 10.9.5
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Have you tried just to only import pygame instead of pygame.base?

Answer (score 0):

In this Stack Overflow question (which is similar to yours) the answer is different and looks like to be more reliable (19 votes up). The question is about the same error you had. Here is the link and I hope it helps you! :

[Installing Pygame for Mac OS X 10.6.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275808/installing-pygame-for-mac-os-x-10-6-8)

It might be a different OSX version, but it should work.