# How can I fix this error from pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I think I have downloaded pygame wrong. Whenever I try to import and initialize it I always get this error:

> ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper

Can someone explain what this is?

Comment: There is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775948/no-matching-architecture-in-universal-wrapper-when-importing-pygame

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["no matching architecture in universal wrapper" when importing pygame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775948/no-matching-architecture-in-universal-wrapper-when-importing-pygame)

Comment: True, but those answers are quite a bit out of date (2011 & 2013). The preferred install method for pygame is now to use the PyPI version.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to install Pygame against the OS X included version of Python.  This is a bad idea for several reasons:

1. It's old - the version that ships with OS X is an older 2.7 release.
2. It's non-standard - Apple has modified it in un-obvious ways.
3. You can't mess with it - you can break your OS X installation if you tinker with it.

For this reason, it is highly recommended that you set up a development environment with a separate, fresh install of Python.  The easiest way to do this is with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), although you can download the installer from http://python.org as well.

While you're at it, I strongly recommend you use Python 3 (the current version is 3.6).  There is no reason for a beginner to be using 2.7.

Once you have Python installed correctly, installing Pygame is as simple as:

```
$ pip3 install pygame
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was baffled by this for quite some time